# what can be a better way to remove empty flowfiles which contents only curly braces

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt, nifi-processor

Is there any better way to remove the empty flowfile which contents only curly braces **{}** .
I have achieved, (attaching the flow for reference) but looking for short and effective method like **Jolt Spec** or any other to reduce the processing time and processor count.

[image: Attaching the screenshot of flowfile content]

[image: And I'm using below approach]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`"@"`** wildcard vs. **`""`** matching nested within a wrapper object notation with key **`"*"`** in a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```